# GCC C "undefined reference to function" error trying to compile/link with a .so library file

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to use a 3rd party library (.so) file in my project. A very simple program to do that:

```
#include "LibGent.h"
#include "genttypes.h"

int main() {
        GT_LIB* gtLib = LibGentGet();
        return 0;
}
```

I compile/link the program above against libgent.so:

```
gcc testing.c -L/home/username/proj -lgent
```

I get the following error:

```
/tmp/ccALOJwU.o: In function `main': testing.c:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `LibGentGet'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, I can see that the function `LibGentGet` is defined in the .so file:

```
readelf -Ws libgent.so | grep "LibGentGet"
301: 0000000000044820     8 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    8 LibGentGet
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: Behavior is as expected, as the symbol is `LOCAL` so it is local to the shared library and not accessable to other objects.  If you want to call it from your program, you'll need to modify the library to export it (make it `GLOBAL`)

Comment: Since the function is local, it's not intended to be called by client code. You should check the library documentation to see how you're supposed to use it.

Comment: This is essentially like trying to call a private method from outside the class in C++.

Comment: @Chris Dodd, @ Barmar -- that makes sense, the library authors asked me to use that function but they forgot to make it global it seems. The code works for VS/Windows .lib but now my guess is they did infact make it global for the windows libs. Thanks for the insight!